# Laravel: How to limit the time attempts in Query or Preventing a Query in 30 seconds?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Here's the scenario. I cannot explain it in a good simple english, so it is like saying:

> "Hey you just request a query a while ago, please wait 30 seconds to query back.
>   For the meantime, use the cached data".

I have a view "application.blade.php", if you open that page it queries something from the Controller

```
 SELECT * FROM application WHERE user_id = 3
```

or

```
  $data = Application::findOrFail(3);
  return view('application', $data); `
```

so if a user will open that page/view, it will show some data. In my case, what if a user keeps refreshing/opening that page, so it will trigger the database to multiple query results. Which can cause traffic or such.

**Question** How to prevent a situation like this. or How to code like this algorithm

```
 if (query_time < 30 sec)
 {
    display_view_using_cache;
 }
```

The reason why this should be implemented, because as far as my boss concern, he don't want the database to be overflooded with query request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', 60, function()
{
    return Application::findOrFail(3);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, my first time to use Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a cache layer - Redis/Memcache/MongoDB. Or reversed proxy, like Varnish. You don't need to check that in code like that.

Then the cache layer code can look like that:

```
if ($cache->has($key)) {
  $response = $cache->fetch($key);
} else {
  $reponse = $db->fetch('whatever');
}
```

and of course in cache layer you can configure for how long given data should be stored.

Of course if You will use Varnish, there won't be much code, it would be on Varnish configuration layer. But I wouldn't suggest reverse proxy in that case. Redis is more than enough.